# TV show about a town where several classic monsters live

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is going to be quite difficult as my memory of the show has faded.

It was a show about a small village where several characters related to classical horror films lived. I remember a werewolf, a vampire and a Frankenstein's monster. Despite this, the tone of the show wasn't horror, it was more about comedy/romance. I recall the romance between Frankenstein's monster and a blond girl as being one of the main plots.

The setting was non-contemporary. I don't recall exactly if it was XIX century or earlier as I was too young to differentiate exactly anything like that.

Adding more details on the show. There were usually exterior shoot scenes, the ambience of the scenery were somewhat "Princess Bride" style.

Also, the show was in full color, not black and white.

I'm not quite sure, but I think the production was from Eastern Europe. I watched it in the mid/late eighties in Spain, dubbed, so the production could have been between late seventies to late eighties.

Comment: *The Munsters* was a comedy that had a range of monsters and a ordinary blonde girl

Comment: XIX? I'm reasonably certain that I wouldn't have been Nineteenth Century....

Comment: *Dark Shadows* feels like it could match. While most of the narrative was in the present day, there were flashbacks and time travel to earlier days.

Comment: although it sure sounds from the premise like it must be a comedy, it would be interesting how to do it as a straight drama/horror. Perhaps the town could be like in The Prisoner and it is sort of like witness protection with the monsters trying to both hide and control their evil impulses. Maybe an episode where humans stumble into town, which has an inn and even is apparently touristy (gov agents use inn and the town tries to look normal) but they are warned not to spend the night despite vacancies at the hotel.

Comment: _[Frankenstein's Aunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein%27s_Aunt#Television_series)_ (1987)...?

Comment: [Frankentsein's Aunt intro](https://youtu.be/WEiv7lL9bTc?si=reWgj8r8SvYl6Zwu)

Comment: Could it be the 1970s live action TV show called [Monster Squad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Squad) (no relation to movie of same name)?

Comment: @releseabe - check out The Gates, a 1-season drama from 2010 about a suburban neighborhood housing werewolves, vampires, witches, ...  It wasn't bad, but didn't last long.

Comment: Not the right answer, but a similar, relatively recent series with other kind of monsters living in the small town town: [Once upon a Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_(TV_series)), with Jennifer Morrison of House MD fame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it could be ***Frankensteins Tante*** also known as *Frankenstein's Aunt*.

From the [Spanish Wikipedia page](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_t%C3%ADa_de_Frankenstein) (translated into English):

> *Frankenstein's Aunt* (*Frankensteins tante*) is a television series produced between Austria, Germany, France, Spain, Czechoslovakia and Sweden in 1987. Based on the Swedish novel of the same name by Allan Gune Petterson, it was directed by Czechoslovakian Juraj Jakubisko and stars Viveca Lindfors, Sancho Gracia, Mercedes Sampietro, Eddie Constantine and Flavio Bucci.
>
> [...]
>
> Henry Frankenstein, in an attempt to emulate his grandfather, Dr. Frankenstein, makes the smartest brain and the strongest body available to him to create a living being, a unique human being. This new being will be called Albert.
>
> Alarmed Henry's aunt, Hannah Frankenstein, heads to her nephew's castle to bring some order to his crazy life and change things in the castle where he lives.
>
> Along with Henry and his new creation, Albert, live other unique characters such as Dracula (who now works as a dentist), Mr Walker (who popularized Lon Chaney Junior, now employed as a librarian), the hunchback Igor (brought back to life after his execution on the gallows) and The White Lady (the ghost of an impared woman, who lives an idyll with Igor). All of them will collaborate as much as possible with the objectives proposed by their aunt.
>
> On the other hand, in the nearby village, a furious citizen who feels threatened by the mysterious activities of the castle, draws up a sinister plan to stop them.

Comment: Also released as a film under the title of *Freckled Max and the Spooks*

Comment: I think we have a winner. Surprisingly I didn't remember that was a co-production with spanish actors involved (some of then as famous as Sancho Gracia from Curro Jimenez show), but the appareance of Jubaj Jakubisko as writer and director has jumped to my memory almost as fast as I saw it. That curious name undoubtfully made an impact in my childhood memory :-)

Comment: In some places, the music of the intro sounds a bit like an adaptation of Star Trek's  Doomsday Machine theme :)

Answer (score 4):

One more:
[**Transylvania_6-5000**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transylvania_6-5000_(1985_film)), [YouTube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulPZNXkpa5s&t=57s)

There are **Frankenstein**, **Wolfman** and **vampire**.

It is 1985 **American/Yugoslav** horror comedy film.

And there is a girl (playing with Frankenstein):

[image]

Plot

> Jack Harrison (Jeff Goldblum) and Gil Turner (Ed Begley Jr.) are
> writers for The Sensation, a supermarket-grade tabloid run by Turner's
> father, Mac Turner (Norman Fell). Jack is a more serious journalist,
> using The Sensation as a stepping stone to a better career and aspires
> to work for Time magazine, while Gil is a gangling yes-man, ever ready
> to win his father's approval.
>
> When Mac receives a homemade videotape of two panicked men running
> from a creature they believe to be Frankenstein's monster, along with
> a waist-down shot of the suspected monster, he dispatches his son and
> Jack to Transylvania to follow the lead. Jack tries unsuccessfully to
> beg off, but is told by Mac that if they both again come back with
> nothing, they are both fired. They have to bring a story that will
> bring a banner headline "Frankenstein Lives!"
>
> Planes, trains and buses later, Jack and Gil arrive at their
> destination. Once off the bus, Jack immediately spots Elizabeth
> Ellison, a pretty female tourist (Teresa Ganzel) from New York City,
> whom he propositions. Gil immediately sets out on their assignment,
> just as quickly drawing hysterical ridicule when he tries to question
> a hotel desk clerk about the whereabouts of Frankenstein, who shares
> Gil's inquiries with the staff and patrons, including the mayor
> Lepescu (Jeffrey Jones).
>
> Jack rescues Gil and pulls him out of the hotel to avoid further
> embarrassment. Both then take off for their hotel. Seeing them leave,
> a gypsy woman named Madame Morovia (Inge Appelt) orders her male
> companion to bring them to her.
>
> Jack and Gil arrive at their hotel, which resembles a 17th-century
> castle, complete with a gated entrance, but adorned with an "Opening
> Soon!" banner and signs denoting the acceptance of credit cards. They
> are met at the gate by Fejos (Michael Richards), a butler with an odd
> sense of humor. They meet for brunch with Lepescu, where they also
> meet Radu (John Byner), his hunched-over manservant who addresses
> everyone as "master" and his wife Lupi (Carol Kane).
>
> Both Gil and Jack learn that something is amiss about Transylvania,
> despite being laughed off by the locals, including Inspector Percek
> (Božidar Smiljanić), head of the local police. After meeting Morovia,
> who tells them they must continue their pursuit, they encounter a
> series of real-life horror creatures, including a Wolfman Larry
> (Donald Gibb), a nymphomaniac vampire Odette (Geena Davis), and a
> swamp monster Twisto that grabs Gil by the crotch as he tries to
> escape a frightening face-to-face confrontation with the object of
> their mission himself.
>
> They eventually learn of a Sicilian doctor, Victorio Malavaqua (Joseph
> Bologna), who lost his license to practice medicine. Finding out that
> Malavaqua has been giving care in a sanitorium, Gil tries to go there
> to make an appointment but is rebuffed by the guard. Gil eventually
> sneaks in and finds Percek and Malavaqua talking about the latter's
> "experiments", including one involving a patient, Kurt Hunyadi, that
> fits the description of the Frankenstein monster, which Malavaqua
> claimed had died. An exhumation of the body later proves otherwise.
>
> Gil learns that Radu is in cahoots with Malavaqua, serving as his lab
> assistant. Malavaqua also displays a tendency towards madness when
> within the confines of his laboratory, but returns to normal when he
> leaves it. It is later revealed, as Gil and Jack go on a search for
> Elizabeth's missing daughter Laura, that not only has Malavaqua faked
> Hunyadi's death, but is also his creator, along with that of Odette,
> Larry, and Twisto. It is also revealed that Malavaqua has engaged in
> this type of bizarre work to clear his family's name.
>
> The story ties together after Jack is attacked by the Wolfman. In an
> attempt to rescue Jack, Gil pulls him off Jack, only to be carted off
> by the Wolfman. The police arrive, but refuse to listen to Jack's
> story and order him put in the local police lockup. Elizabeth rescues
> him and learns that the entire police force is at the wine festival
> instead of searching for her missing daughter. Jack heads off to
> Malavaqua's lab and Elizabeth goes to the festival. As she is being
> hauled away by police after confronting Percek, the town is horrified
> as the monster returns in the flesh, carrying Laura in his arms.
> Perceived to be dead, it is later learned she was just sleeping.
>
> Jack and Gil arrive, having confronted Malavaqua, and explain
> Malavaqua's actions to the townspeople, that Malavaqua was
> legitimately trying to create normal lives for those seen as outcasts
> or freaks by the townspeople, who now welcome them with open arms.
>
> Finding out that the story is even bigger than what they bargained
> for, Gil takes enough pictures and both gather enough material to last
> weeks for the tabloid. They more than make up for their failures and
> Mac gets his banner headline.

Comment: Sadly it isn't. As I stated above, this was a TV Show, not a movie.

Answer (score 3):

Could be [**The_Monster_Squad**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_Squad),
[YouTube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbtFKZQUepw)

[image]

> ...**Dracula** seeks to obtain the amulet so that he can take
> over the world. To this end, he assembles several monstrous allies:
> **The Mummy, the Gill-man, The Wolf Man**, and three school girls whom the
> Count transforms into his vampiric consorts. Dracula then steals a
> crate from a B-25 Mitchell in flight, containing Frankenstein's
> monster, thus completing his army. **However, Frankenstein's monster is
> reluctant to aid Dracula**, and wanders into the forest **where he
> encounters Phoebe. Rather than being afraid, she shows him the
> kindness he has always sought, and they become friends**.

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't, this was a TV Show, not a movie, also it's placed in a non contemporary setting, I'll add that to my question, as I forgot to say that.

Answer (score 3):

[The Munsters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Munsters) was a US TV show that ran from 1964 to 1966.

> The Munsters are a Transylvanian-American family living at 1313 Mockingbird Lane in the fictional city of Mockingbird Heights. The series' running gag is that the odd-looking family with strange tastes considers itself to be an average American family.

[image: The Munsters]

The dad is Frankenstein's monster. Grandpa is Dracula and mum is also a Vampire. The son is wolf-like and/or a werewolf.

I would describe it as a less horror version of [The Adamms family.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Addams_Family_(1964_TV_series))

Comment: It's not the Munsters nor the Addams Family, this was a full color show it wasn't black and white.

Comment: @Bardo The pilot of The Munsters was in color, then they went black-and-white for the rest of the series

Comment: I remember clearly watching several episodes in color. I had also watched The Munsters and remember them perfectly, they are not the show I'm looking for.

Comment: There was no romance between the blonde and Frankenstein's monster -- that would have been incest.

Answer (score 3):

Could be **Drácula contra Frankenstein AKA Dracula, Prisoner of Frankenstein** **(1972)**.

The film depicts Dracula, Frankenstein, a werewolf and a ginger (not blonde) girl.

Here a synopsis:

> Dracula kills another innocent victim and Dr. Seward decides it's time to wipe him off the face of the earth. Armed with a hammer and a wooden stake, he arrives at Castle Dracula and duly dispatches the vampire Count. Next day, however, Dr. Frankenstein arrives with his assistant, Morpho, and a large crate containing the monster. Using the blood of a pub singer who has been abducted by his creation, the doctor brings Dracula back to life and uses him for his own ends. The Count and a female vampire continue to terrorize the town, so Dr Seward once again sets out for Castle Dracula. Unfortunately, he is attacked by the Frankenstein monster and left for dead. Amira, a gypsy, rescues him and summons up a werewolf to do battle with the forces of evil...

Here one poster and a couple of still images.

[image: Poster of Drácula contra Frankenstein (1972)]

[image: Still image 1 of Drácula contra Frankenstein (1972)]

[image: Still image 2 of Drácula contra Frankenstein (1972)]

Here the IMDB link:

[Drácula contra Frankenstein (1972)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065660)